# Laravel using a different users table returns 419 page expired

Tags: php, laravel

I am attempting to use a different user table for authentication on my Laravel project the idea is to have the default user table and a members table both have email and password fields on it.

here is my config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'members' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'members_auth',
        ],
    ],

     

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
        'members_auth'  => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => App\Models\Members::class,
        ],
 
    ],
```

and then i run `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

and change my members model in to this

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

class Members extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
    use Authenticatable;
```

And then on MembersController authenticate function

```
public function authenticate(Request $request){
    $formFields = $request->validate([
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

   
    //authenticate user
    if(Auth::guard('members')->attempt($formFields)){
        
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        
        return redirect('/')->with('message', 'Welcome back! Here are some items you missed when you were gone.');
    }

    return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Invalid Credentials'])->onlyInput('email');
}
```

And i got route and my login form configured also like below i already tried @csrf and putting SESSION_DOMAIN= on my .env file but still 419 error after login.

```
<form class="mt-8 space-y-6" action="/members/authenticate" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Comment: Multi Auth is available since Laravel 8, which version are you using?
If this is a fresh Laravel 8 install your configuration should be correct.
If you're upgrading from an older version you need to run an extra migration to add a provider column in oauth_access_token_providers table.

Comment: I manage to solved it turns out that i been using the default web auth middleware protection on my routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it shows 419 page because of the middleware route protection so i just  added to my routes.

from

```
Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController:: class, 'dashboard'])->middleware('auth');
```

to

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:web,members'] ], function(){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [HomeController::class, 'dashboard']);
});
```